# GA Average Time On Page In BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble working out average time on page from the back end GA BigQuery export data and wondering if someone might see if code below looks reasonable.

I'm having trouble getting it to match that from query explorer tool.

Is there a way to run query explorer tool for the LondonCycleHelmet data?

Any help much appreciated, thanks

```
select
  pageviews,
  exit_pageviews,
  sum_hit_length_seconds,
  sum_hit_length_seconds / (pageviews - exit_pageviews) as avg_time_on_page
from
  (
  select 
    SUM(hit_length_seconds) as sum_hit_length_seconds, 
    COUNT(IF(hits.type='PAGE',(CONCAT(session_key,'_',hits.page.hostname,'_',hits.page.pagePath)),NULL)) AS pageviews,
    COUNT(IF((next_hit_time is null) or (hits.hitNumber=hits_hitNumber_max),(CONCAT(session_key,'_',hits.page.hostname,'_',hits.page.pagePath)),NULL)) AS exit_pageviews,
  from
    (
    select
      *,
      (next_hit_time-hits.time)/1000 as hit_length_seconds,
    from
      (
      select
        fullVisitorId,
        visitId,
        visitorId,
        hits.type,
        hits.time,
        hits.hitNumber,
        hits.page.hostname,
        hits.page.pagePath,
        -- create some keys to handle data later
        concat(fullVisitorId,"_",string(visitId)) as session_key,
        concat(fullVisitorId,"_",string(visitId),"_",string(hits.hitNumber),"_",string(hits.time)) as hit_key,
        -- get max and min number of hits for each session
        MAX(hits.hitNumber) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_hitNumber_max,
        MIN(hits.hitNumber) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_hitNumber_min,    
        -- get min and max hit times to work out full session length
        MAX(hits.time) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_time_max,
        MIN(hits.time) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_time_min,        
        -- get next and previous hit time to be able to work out length of each hit
        LAG(hits.time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as previous_hit_time,
        LEAD(hits.time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as next_hit_time,
      from
        [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] 
      )
    )
  )
```

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION**:

I think it's when i look at an individual page across time that it starts going out of whack.

For example if i run below in BigQuery:

```
select
  pageviews,
  exit_pageviews,
  sum_hit_length_seconds,
  sum_hit_length_seconds / (pageviews - exit_pageviews) as avg_time_on_page
from
  (
  select 
    SUM(hit_length_seconds) as sum_hit_length_seconds, 
    COUNT(IF(hits.type='PAGE',(CONCAT(session_key,'_',hits.page.hostname,'_',hits.page.pagePath)),NULL)) AS pageviews,
    COUNT(IF((next_hit_time is null) or (hits.hitNumber=hits_hitNumber_max),(CONCAT(session_key,'_',hits.page.hostname,'_',hits.page.pagePath)),NULL)) AS exit_pageviews,
  from
    (
    select
      *,
      (next_hit_time-hits.time)/1000 as hit_length_seconds,
    from
      (
      select
        fullVisitorId,
        visitId,
        visitorId,
        hits.type,
        hits.time,
        hits.hitNumber,
        hits.page.hostname,
        hits.page.pagePath,
        -- create some keys to handle data later
        concat(fullVisitorId,"_",string(visitId)) as session_key,
        concat(fullVisitorId,"_",string(visitId),"_",string(hits.hitNumber),"_",string(hits.time)) as hit_key,
        -- get max and min number of hits for each session
        MAX(hits.hitNumber) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_hitNumber_max,
        MIN(hits.hitNumber) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_hitNumber_min,    
        -- get min and max hit times to work out full session length
        MAX(hits.time) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_time_max,
        MIN(hits.time) WITHIN RECORD AS hits_time_min,        
        -- get next and previous hit time to be able to work out length of each hit
        LAG(hits.time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as previous_hit_time,
        LEAD(hits.time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as next_hit_time,
      from
        [XXX.ga_sessions_20151001],
        [XXX.ga_sessions_20151002],
        [XXX.ga_sessions_20151003],
      where
        hits.page.pagePath='/2015/10/01/blah-blah/'            
      )
    )
  )
```

I get:

[
  {
    "pageviews": "24002",
    "exit_pageviews": "22468",
    "sum_hit_length_seconds": "455762.1240000001",
    "avg_time_on_page": "297.10699087353333"
  }
]

But if i look at query explorer like this:

[image: ga-query-exlorer-settings]

I get:

[image: ga-query-exlorer-results]

So it looks like pageviews match but both exits and time on page seem quite different and i cant figure out why.

Can anyone recreate this example on your own data?

Have a feeling its to do with how exits and time on page are calculate in GA but could not find any examples in BQ GA cookbook of how to calculate time on page or exits.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the query explorer. you can copy this query straight in the explorer and it works.  Anyway, it looks good from what I can see.

Comment: i mean the GA developer thingy : https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: AH! thanks for the clarification. I thought you meant the BQ GUI. I don't know much about the analytics side of it though

Comment: i ask because the sql query does not match what i get when i use the ga query explorer. and its the ga query explorer that lines up with the front end. but problem is that i cant point ga query explorer at london cycle helmets so means i can't really give full picture here.

Comment: p.s. this is the logic as per query explorer - so if you point it at one of your own sites and also change the from table in above sql you should see the discrepancy i am talking about. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-10-01&end-date=2015-10-01&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AtimeOnPage%2Cga%3AavgTimeOnPage%2Cga%3Aexits&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=1000

Comment: hmmmm I wonder if this might be because the GA schema has repeated fields and the count is weird on BQ because of that? In the general sense, I would trust GA more than BQ in that instance. Maybe if you try some flattening over the proper tables, it'll help?

Comment: It's not clear to me that the "exitPageviews"/"pageviews" counts matches how GA defines duration. I am not an expert on the GA side, so I could easily be wrong here, but from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en it looks like duration has a couple of odd cases. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925972/average-time-on-page-vs-average-visit-duration-on-google-analytics it also looks like average time on page isn't entirely accurate either.

Comment: Is this still an issue for anyone?  Was any explanation found about how `time on page` and `page exits` are calculated?

Comment: Exit rate is defined quite concretely in the [Google Analytics Help docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2525491?hl=en).

Comment: The most recent comment by Michael Sheldon seems to function as a sort of higher-level answer to the motivation of this question: avg time on page is not easy to measure and will have skew - sometimes quite significant - and therefore it's best not to obsess about it but to take it with a grain of salt. Now this leaves the question as to why the output from the GA dev tools site linked in prior comments is different from your query.

Comment: Not being a developer on the GA dev tools site, and not having access to the queries produced by it, I can't speak on the question as to why the tool reported something different to what your query produced.